# Rmarkdown to pdf: change plot margins without showing the code resposible for changing the margins

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown

using the below code for generating a pdf document via Rmarkdown. I'm adjusting the margins of the plot to get the plot closer to the main text or code (as suggested in one of the other questions). What I would like to do is adjust the margins, but without the reader of the pdf seeing the code I used. I know I can use echo=FALSE to hide a code chunk, but I would like to hide only one line in the whole chunk. Is this possible?

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "Tuesday, September 30, 2014"
output: pdf_document
---

The combination of code below does not change the margins
```{r,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
par(mar=c(5, 4, 0, 2))
```

```{r,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
rns<-runif(10000)
rns_n<-(rnorm(10000))
hist(rns)
```
\newpage

**But this does**

```{r,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
par(mar=c(5, 4, 0, 2))
rns<-runif(10000)
rns_n<-(rnorm(10000))
hist(rns)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `knitr` [docs](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

> besides TRUE/FALSE which completely turns on/off the source code, we
>   can also use a numeric vector to select which R expression(s) to echo
>   in a chunk, e.g. echo=2:3 means only echo the 2nd and 3rd expressions,
>   and echo=-4 means to exclude the 4th expression

Comment: Thanks Roman. Obvious now I know where to find it. Had been looking through the Rmarkdown website. So from the knitr docs it is under Options - Chunk Options - Text Results.